# TypeScript return type of a generic method of a class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I cannot get the type of a generic method in a class, trying to do that results in a parse error.

```
class MyClass<T extends string> {
  public myMethod<U extends string>(arg: U): [T, U] {

  }
}

type returnType = ReturnType<MyClass<'test'>['myMethod']<'test'>>;
// Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?(1382)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Update: I have edited the example to avoid confusion, the type previously being unknown was only to make the example simple. Also the return type depends on both the class generic and method generic.

Also, it's not possible to just isolate the method like

```
type method = MyClass<'test'>['myMethod']

type returnType = ReturnType<method<'test'>>;
```

because `method` is not a generic. And making it a generic results in the very same parse error.

Update2: <it's not an issue with the return type but the type itself specifically - I will keep the original question though. I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53410).

Comment: I think they did it as the question is very lite (as it wasn't containing question) and/or because the use of the `['myMethod']` into the type could just help to break everything

Comment: For your problem: if you don't know the type of generic (as you wrote `unknown`) you will not be able to get the return type, so for me it's not possible

Comment: This is just the simplest example. The issue is a parse error so it does not matter what the generic is - there should be a way to get the type somehow.

Comment: @Mafii I did edit it slightly though, I see how the previous version could have come across as someone just starting to learn how to code looking for help lol

Comment: I have submitted an issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53410

Comment: Instantiation expressions are *expressions*, not types. If you have a function type like `type X = <T>(x: T) => T[]`, you can't write `type Y = X<string>`.  You can only write `declare const x: X;  const y = x<string>; type Y = typeof Y;`.  You simply *must* drop to the expression level to do this; it's impossible in pure type-space.  In your case it could look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMXJlN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes that explains it, thank you. I will accept your answer if you post it. There's also the solution shared by another user on the GitHub issue - the one with the prototype access is most neat.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance; I doubt the prototype method will work on the class generic (which is different here from the version in your github issue) and you'd get `[any, 'test']` or something.  Can you do better with the prototype? If so, could you demonstrate?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have just found out - I'm getting a parse error.

Comment: @jcalz Just tested on my real case and your solution works. There's one thing I had to change, I cannot seem to use declare keyword, I'm getting a TypeScript error. I replaced `declare const` with `let`. I'm guessing that the runtime result is `let x; const y = x;` which is valid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in TypeScript; generic *types* (class instance types, interfaces, and type aliases) and generic *functions* (generic call signatures, methods, and even generic construct signatures).

---

A generic *type*'s generic type parameter is scoped to the type, and you need to specify the type argument to even refer to the type.  So in

```
class MyClass<T extends string> {
  public myMethod<U extends string>(arg: U): [T, U] {

  }
}
```

The type of an instance of the `MyClass` constructor value needs to have a type argument... you can't just write `MyClass` by itself as an instance type. You need something like `MyClass<"testT">`:

```
type MyClassInstance = MyClass<"testT">;
// type MyClassInstance = MyClass<"testT">
```

And now we have a specific type.  Every instance of type `MyClassInstance<"testT">` has a `myMethod` method, so we should be able to [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `MyClassInstance` to get the type of that method:

```
type MyClassInstanceMethod = MyClassInstance["myMethod"];
// type MyClassInstanceMethod = <U extends string>(arg: U) => ["testT", U]
```

And here we see the other kind of generic.

---

The type `MyClassInstanceMethod` is not itself generic; it takes no type parameter.  But the type is the type of a generic *function*, whose call signature is `<U extends string>(arg: U) => ["testT", U]`.  A generic function's type parameter is scoped to the call signature.  You do *not* specify the type argument to refer to the type; the type argument is generally only specified when someone actually calls a function of that type.  It is impossible to do it purely from within the type system.

So you can't specify `U` from the definition of `MyClassInstanceMethod`. If you try, you will get the error that `MyClassInstanceMethod` is not generic:

```
type Nope = MyClassInstanceMethod<"testU">; // error!
// Type 'MyClassInstanceMethod' is not generic.
```

The only way to specify `U` here is to get ahold of a *value* of type `MyClassInstanceMethod`, or at least convince the compiler that you have one:

```
declare const myClassInstanceMethod: MyClassInstanceMethod; // or
// const myClassInstanceMethod = (() => { }) as Function as MyClassInstanceMethod;
```

Before TypeScript 4.7, the only way you proceed there would be to actually call that function:

```
const ret = myClassInstanceMethod<"testU">("testU"); // okay
// const ret: ["testT", "testU"];
```

But with TypeScript 4.7 and above, you could use an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) to specify a generic function's type arguments *without* calling it:

```
const myClassInstanceMethodSpecified = myClassInstanceMethod<"testU">;
// const myClassInstanceMethodSpecified: (arg: "testU") => ["testT", "testU"]

type R = ReturnType<typeof myClassInstanceMethodSpecified>;
// type R = ["testT", "testU"]
```

which is finally the type you want.

---

To recap, the only way to specify a generic function's type argument is to drop down briefly to the value level, and then you can jump back up to the type level afterward.  Thus the minimal number of lines here is probably two:

```
declare const m: MyClass<'testT'>['myMethod'];
type R = ReturnType<typeof m<'testU'>>;
// type R = ["testT", "testU"]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGCPAJwEtCBzAPmgG8AoaaABwFcAjEK4NAC28WFjwALAPbFUAVWz4ipaOWp16ACjAVaALmhyAlAYDa6ADSGAuszbtoFcVwqFohLiBABCewF8WAJY8eA4sOCQUCABJQnIwQmBwgF4I5EgIVAAiAnJ0LPoAbhYAehLoELC0qNj4xJTqjOzcvHz6FmDQ8IR0qFq8BKSxSRloVJ6auIH60yyRYeliLOtisoquxr6pwawF0dT5RQISMkoaBm1dA2MxxlmW-Ks5aw7K8IA5KSrxyIz+nb2shyWHIcgKhWgaywFAoUgovjW6A2AHIJn9tvVAcjoFQYIQpHhoLQiNCBAA6DplYhYUA6cLAKRTYS-LZ1IbiRYGNGs6bskbEYoMpkiXoxDF8xZjaCaTRGW7MaB+OWQaAAMS4iTwVEZ0BV3LFbN2HJkxRYQvIjnEUpFk0NgOaILwYK0wNBWSMELWUgA1mB4KVyubCU48GZXa0slZw2CXmbGRabei7cbiABlMLAKgAMyoWGI1pZBt5Rv5DrdRQD0CDzNF-0xKfTNOzueIBku+mg0fd8vujsenZaMdeGwASlKR85XEiwqg3lIszXbcXAY3Mzm8xW1m9oGPUr28pGB46hyxqbSnFX44ShFzC6hkQ9kfRTMj5inkStOlVU+PJ4Rp1gs5dPOwj3oOT6buU24-nu4b9l2LxAA)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
class MyClass<ClassGeneric> {
  public myMethod<MethodGeneric>(arg: MethodGeneric): void {

  }
}

type ClassMethodType = typeof MyClass.prototype['myMethod'];
// <MethodGeneric>(arg: MethodGeneric) => void
```

I didn't use `ReturnType` because it felt wrong based on how I interpreted your question:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype

Comment: No. Just defining a type to contain the method is not going to work because you are skipping the generic here. Something like `type ClassMethodType<T> = typeof MyClass.prototype['myMethod']<T>`  would solve the problem but it also generates a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
class MyClass<ClassGeneric> {
  public myMethod<MethodGeneric>(arg: MethodGeneric): void {

  }
}

type returnType = MyClass<any>['myMethod'];
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=44&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8zIQOIFMB2OATgJbAB80A3gFDTQAOArgEYinQC28sOALgBYB7ACaoeAkbgIlyACjCEA5gC44fIcKlFSASlUA3QcWFVqtaAF9qV6r3j0c0Qn0aE8AFXuOAvHCQoIVDA8eDIAbQByLnENCIBdAG5qAHpkujoAPQB+IA).

Note:

- you could use pretty much any type instead of `any`, `unknown`, `string`, `{}`

Comment: As I mentioned in my updated  question, the generics are not unknown and the return types depends on both.